# Can't install Homebrew on macOS Mojave; installer doesn't recognize Command Line Tools

Tags: install, xcode, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. To do this, I'm running the command line suggested at the Homebrew website:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Although my computer already has Xcode installed (updated to version 11 a few days ago, according to the version history), the Homebrew installer doesn't seem to be aware of this. Instead, it tries (and fails) to perform a fresh installation of the Command Line Tools.

Here's the output I get in the Terminal window:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
Password:
Timed out while loading data from the Apple Software Update server.
==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup):
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
Password:
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
Press any key when the installation has completed.
```

At this point, the computer displays a dialog box asking me to either (a) install XCode or (b) visit the XCode page in the App Store. Neither of these options does anything useful. (I either get to see a progress bar doing nothing for 5 minutes, or the App Store opens and confirms that, yes, XCode has indeed been installed.)

Is this a temporary issue caused by the version 11 update of XCode? Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: Are you facing an error in [installing-xcode-command-line-tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools?rq=1)

Comment: I, too, had to download the tools .dmg separately from https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.2.dmg, and install the tools. Homebrew then installed with no further problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Xcode command line tools** is a separate package for Xcode

Download **Command Line Tools for Xcode** from developer.apple.com/download/more and install it again.

source: [Installing Xcode Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools)

Useful for troubleshooting

```
xcode-select -p
```

Comment: Easier to type in, perhaps, but this is the command that the Homebrew installer is running of its own accord. It has the correct path for `sudo`; it's just trying to install something that's already there from a source that apparently doesn't exist. (This is where I get the progress bar showing no progress.)

Comment: What does `brew config` output? (assuming the install got you that far) from @ankii's link look for a pkg file that looks like `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS*` and run open on it, like ```open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg``` from @Forcetti https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools looks like the most common solution is to download **Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode** from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Something else useful is output from `xcode-select -p ` and where you think your Xcode resides.

Comment: Homebrew hasn't been installed at all, so the output for `brew config` is, unsurprisingly, `-bash: brew: command not found`. For `xcode-select -p`, I get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: I think the easiest route is to download **Command Line Tools for Xcode** from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and install it.

Answer (score 2):

As a side answer, It’s common for there to be a slight delay when new releases are out due to traffic or Apple taking 12 to 36 hours to seed all the download servers with a new package. Waiting a short term and retrying often works.

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
```

Then install button in the window

[image: choose install in this dialog to install the command line tools without needing Xcode]

An internet connection is needed and the tools will update like other system updates.  You don’t need the Mac App Store or developer downloads for this to work.