# Xcode command line tools install error trying to run homebrew

Tags: xcode, homebrew, error

I am trying to install homebrew but cannot due to an error popping up when I try to install command line tools. The error says that they cannot be downloaded from the install server.

I already checked the library to see if Xcode is there ..nothing. I'm running Catalina.

Note : I only want the command line tools, not the whole 10GB Xcode download, which I heard snoops on your system. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the exact quoted error.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You can download the Xcode command line tools from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode You only need an Apple ID, Apple Developer Program membership is not required.

Comment: "Xcode snoops on your system."...? I'd be very surprised if that were true, in any way. Apple have made their commitment to user privacy very clear, and it would be a major PR gaffe if this could be proved. A quick Google shows nothing of the kind.

Comment: "Cannot install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server"  this is the exact error , weird I'm curious to know why although  yes thanks guys you are correct I can download from their site  .  I used to not care about privacy as there is is a fine line between paranoia and reality , I just don't like the fact someone is collecting information in a mass scale , I guess all we can do is make it difficult for the big corporation mining your data but that is another topic!  proxy , VPN , https everywhere , firevault ..the list goes on down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

This question has my best answer for installing the tools.

- [Can't install Homebrew on macOS Mojave; installer doesn't recognize Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370695/cant-install-homebrew-on-macos-mojave-installer-doesnt-recognize-command-line)

I prefer running it without Xcode or a developer account, but if your are super paranoid on security, perhaps downloading it from Apple developer wen site lets you validate the checksum and sizing before you install it? If you trust Apple updates for security, you should probably trust them for the Xcode tools, though.