# Issue with Xcode CLI tools

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I know Xcode is installed because (1) I can launch it and (2) App Store offers to update it and successfully does so.

But **every** time I launch it, it asks me to install the command-line tools with a GUI pop-up, and makes no complaint of error when I OK that.

And `brew` keeps saying `xcode-select --install` but if I try it it complains

```
xcode-select: error: no developer tools were found, and no install could be requested (perhaps no UI is present), please install manually from 'developer.apple.com'.
```

It does NOT offer the GUI pop-up mentioned in the answer to [Installing Xcode Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools)

Solution?

Comment: I believe, but not sure, **Homebrew** needs the standalone install of **Command Line Tools for Xcode** even if you have **Xcode** installed. If you are having issues with `xcode-select --install` then if you have a **Developer** account, (free or paid), go to [https://developer.apple.com/download/more/](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and manually download it and install.

Comment: What output does running `xcode-select -p` prints in the Terminal?