# Command line tools for Monterey without XCode

Tags: command-line, xcode

I'm extremely surprised this question wasn't asked, or at least I wasn't able to find it.

Is there a way to install command line tools for MacOS without installing the full XCode suite? I'm low on storage and I find it hard to swallow that I have to free up 20+ GB just to be able to do:

```sh
$ python -m http.server
```

Especially since python is already installed...

#### EDIT #2: This was just an example, my question is about xcode cli tools.

I want to be able to use `make`, `gcc`, install `brew` packages etc...

#### EDIT: Replying to the comment and why I think "python is installed"

Simple: Everything was working, until I uninstalled XCode to free up 11GB that I needed (and I don't use XCode at all). Also:

```sh
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel   163K May  9  2022 /usr/bin/python3
$ file /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
- Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
- Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64):     Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64e):     Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
$ hexdump -C /usr/bin/python3 | head
00000000  ca fe ba be 00 00 00 02  01 00 00 07 00 00 00 03  |............|
00000010  00 00 40 00 00 01 0c f0  00 00 00 0e 01 00 00 0c  |..@............|
00000020  80 00 00 02 00 01 80 00  00 01 0c d0 00 00 00 0e  |...............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00004000  cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01  03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |............|
00004010  12 00 00 00 40 06 00 00  85 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  |....@..... .....|
00004020  19 00 00 00 48 00 00 00  5f 5f 50 41 47 45 5a 45  |....H...__PAGEZE|
00004030  52 4f 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |RO..............|
00004040  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
$ md5sum /usr/bin/python3
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/python3
$ python3 -m http.server
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

PS: I know [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339015/214086) exists but it assumes I get to choose anything after running `xcode-select --install` which hasn't been the case since Big Sur as far as I know

Comment: If you truly have python installed already, no, you don't have to install anything else to use `http.server`.  Re the answer you link, it certainly doesn't say what you seem to think it says, even ignoring the Homebrew bias.  If you want the CLT, install the CLT, with `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain why I think I have python installed.

About the the link: "For my machine, running `xcode-select --install` and **choosing** to install the tools from the window that popped up helped fix the problem". Maybe I over-interpreted the word **choosing**.

For me `xcode-select --install` tried to install 20GB worth of data and I don't have the required disk space

Comment: That's the stub, not an actual python install.  It looks like you had a CLT install (which installs python 3.9) and deleted it.

Comment: So you're saying when I uninstalled XCode, it also uninstalled python? Also, I just mentioned `python3 -m http.server` as an example. Before coming to ask this rather straightforward question I was actually trying to `brew install redis`.
The question was: "s there a way to install command line tools for MacOS without installing the full XCode suite?" (and the title hints: "for Monterey").

Comment: If you just want python, install it from python.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

Downloading CLT directly from : https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

At the moment of posting, it's version 14.1: a 704MB download for a 3.4GB installation. Still makes me wonder why but I'll take it.

Just a bit of extra context for the people who commented and replied. The question was:

> Is there a way to install command line tools for MacOS **without installing the full XCode suite**?

(I added boldness here for clarity)

the Python bit was an explanation of why I need CLT, and the

> I have to free up 20+ GB just to be able to do...

was the explanation of why I don't want to install CLT with `xcode-select --install` (which just opened a window asking me to agree to the installation then failed because I needed to free up 21GB).

Comment: Why is because the SDK's are in it.

Answer (score 0):

The `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path` implies that you don't have the CLT installed. As others already said, run `xcode-select --install` to fix this. Homebrew relies on CTL being present, so if you want to run `brew` you must install it.

If all you need is a pre-compiled `python`, download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/.

Comment: My question is: Is there an alternative way that doesn't take 20+GB ?

Comment: My CLT install is ~3gb, and I installed it with `xcode-select --install`.  This laptop has never had Xcode on it.

Comment: @MarcWilson on Monterey ? When I run that command, it doesn't give me any option and immediately tries to download XCode (and fails because I don't have the free space)

Comment: Yes, witht that command.

Comment: @MarcWilson you didn't answer to: "on Monterey?"

Comment: There are no options to that command, and no, it doesn't download Xcode.  Yes,. on Monterey.